# How to get model parameters w when using LS-SVM lab?

Tags: matlab, svm

I can get `alpha` and `b` with the following MATLAB code:

```
model = initlssvm(trainX,trainY,'c',10,[],'lin_kernel');
model = trainlssvm(model);
b = model.b;
alpha = model.alpha;
```

When I want to calculate the model parameter `w` with the formulation:

> w = sum(alpha_i * y_i * x_i)

```
w = zeros(1,size(trainX,2));
for j = 1 : size(trainX,1)
    w = w + alpha(j)*trainY(j,:).*trainX(j,:);
end
```

and then I use the following code to check whether the value of `w` is right:

```
for i = 1 : size(testX,1)
    pre = sign(w * testX(i,:)'+b);
    pres = [pres; pre];
end
```

However, the result shows that the value of `w` that I got is wrong.

How to get the right `w` of lssvm?